# Catching event on collection load

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Lets say I have this class:

```
class Parent(Base):
    children = relationship(Child)

class Child(Base):
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
    sex = Column(String)
    is_married = Column(Boolean)
    is_working = Column(Boolean)
```

I would like  have some read-only attributes that I want to compute, like `has_single_daughters` or `has_working_sons`. I could make a method like:

```
class Parent(Base):
    children = relationship(Child)

    def has_working_sons(self):
        for child in children:
            if child.is_working:
                return True
        return False
```

But imagine the performance hit if we query a lot of parents, each having a few children. I would like to kind of cache each property computing it a single time, something like this:

```
class Parent(Base):
    children = relationship(Child)

    def on_load_or_update_children_collection(self):
        for child in self.children:
            if child.is_working:
                if child.sex == 'M':
                    self.has_working_sons = True
            # ... and so on and so forth
```

In this case, `on_load_children` should be linked to a collection event, but I haven't found anything that works. I eagerly load my related attribute by using `joinedload` in some queries.

Is there any event or any other method I can use for this?

Comment: You could create a `Parent.working_children` relationship attribute, but specify an [Alternate Join Condition](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#specifying-alternate-join-conditions) (something like `'and_(Parent.id == Child.parent_id, child.is_working == 1'`). Then you could eager load that relationship too..

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution which I believe is efficient and will allow you to easily create read only properties based upon combinations of `Child` attributes through using `set` as the relationship's [`collection_class`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.collection_class).

You can use the [Alternate Join Condition](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#specifying-alternate-join-conditions) idiom in order to create relationship attributes that are subsets of the set of a `Parent`'s children, for example here is a relationship that will return all female children:

```
female_children = sa.orm.relationship(
    'Child', collection_class=set,
    primaryjoin='and_(Parent.id == Child.parent_id, Child.sex == "female")'
)
```

I won't go into explaining that too much as it's very similar to the documented examples which have been linked to above, except note the specification of  `collection_class=set`, the importance of which will be apparent later on.

I've gone on to create a similar relationship for each possible categorisation of a `Child`, again, all `collection_class=set`:

```
class Parent(Base):
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)

    children = sa.orm.relationship('Child', collection_class=set)
    male_children = sa.orm.relationship(
        'Child', collection_class=set,
        primaryjoin='and_(Parent.id == Child.parent_id, Child.sex == "male")'
    )
    female_children = sa.orm.relationship(
        'Child', collection_class=set,
        primaryjoin='and_(Parent.id == Child.parent_id, Child.sex == "female")'
    )
    working_children = sa.orm.relationship(
        'Child', collection_class=set,
        primaryjoin='and_(Parent.id == Child.parent_id, Child.is_working == True)'
    )
    married_children = sa.orm.relationship(
        'Child', collection_class=set,
        primaryjoin='and_(Parent.id == Child.parent_id, Child.is_married == True)'
    )
```

The child model is as you've defined (except for the string lengths as I'm working with MySQL):

```
class Child(Base):
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('parent.id'))
    sex = sa.Column(sa.String(6))
    is_married = sa.Column(sa.Boolean)
    is_working = sa.Column(sa.Boolean)
```

Here's some test data:

```
s = Session()
parent = Parent()
s.add(parent)
parent.children.update([
    Child(sex='male', is_married=True, is_working=False),
    Child(sex='female', is_married=True, is_working=True),
    Child(sex='male', is_married=False, is_working=True)
])
s.commit()
```

When you query for the `Parent`, `joinedload` all of the relationships so that you are only making a single round trip to the db (as you've stated that efficiency is a concern, although this isn't strictly necessary, lazy loading will work fine too):

```
parent = s.query(Parent).options(sa.orm.joinedload('*')).first()
print(parent.children)
# InstrumentedSet({Child(is_married=False, id=3, is_working=True, sex=male, parent_id=1), Child(is_married=True, id=2, is_working=True, sex=female, parent_id=1), Child(is_married=True, id=1, is_working=False, sex=male, parent_id=1)})
print(parent.female_children)
# InstrumentedSet({Child(is_married=True, id=2, is_working=True, sex=female, parent_id=1)})
print(parent.male_children)
# InstrumentedSet({Child(is_married=False, id=3, is_working=True, sex=male, parent_id=1), Child(is_married=True, id=1, is_working=False, sex=male, parent_id=1)})
print(parent.married_children)
# InstrumentedSet({Child(is_married=True, id=2, is_working=True, sex=female, parent_id=1), Child(is_married=True, id=1, is_working=False, sex=male, parent_id=1)})
```

As the relationship attributes on `Parent` are all [`sets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) it allows for very efficient operations on them. For example here's an isolation of working, male children:

```
print(parent.working_children & parent.male_children)
# {Child(is_married=False, id=3, is_working=True, sex=male, parent_id=1)}
```

You can then define whatever read only properties on your `Parent` model that you like, here's some examples:

```
class Parent(Base):

    ### excluded all of the columns and relationships for brevity ###

    @property
    def working_sons(self):
        return self.working_children & self.male_children

    @property
    def working_daughters(self):
        return self.working_children & self.female_children

    @property
    def unmarried_children(self):
        return self.children - self.married_children

    @property
    def married_unemployed_sons(self):
        return (
            self.male_children - self.working_children & self.married_children)

print(parent.working_sons)
# {Child(is_married=False, id=3, is_working=True, sex=male, parent_id=1)}
print(parent.working_daughters)
# {Child(is_married=True, id=2, is_working=True, sex=female, parent_id=1)}
print(parent.unmarried_children)
# {Child(is_married=False, id=3, is_working=True, sex=male, parent_id=1)}
print(parent.married_unemployed_sons)
# {Child(is_married=True, id=1, is_working=False, sex=male, parent_id=1)}
```

As these are all set operations, they are very efficient but you could cache the result of them upon first access if desired.

Your question specifically references a `bool` property, `has_working_sons`, so you could either use the truthiness of the `Parent.working_sons` property when testing if the `Parent` has a working son (e.g. `if parent.working_sons: ...`) or use `bool(Parent.working_sons)` if you really need it to be a `True`/`False`.